# What are the Vedic Shaiva Agamas being discussed in the following verses of the Shiva Puranas?

Tags: shiva, shaivism, shiva-purana, agamas, pashupata-shaivism

The Shiva Purana [mentions the following](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226668.html) -

> The Śaiva Āgama is of two varieties: Śrauta (Vedic) and
> Aśrauta (Unvedic). The Śrauta consists of condensed Vedic texts; the
> other one consists of independent texts but well consecrated.
>
> The independent texts were originally ten but supplemented
> subsequently by eight more so as to constitute eighteen texts. They
> are called Kāmika etc., and the entire literature is called “Śaiva
> Siddhānta”
>
> The Śrauta literature consists of a billion verses. In it the Pāśupata
> Vrata and Jñāna are explained.

Which Srauta (Vedic) Saivagama is being alluded to in these verses?

Comment: I think, the aśrauta āgamas are the āgamas accepted by Śaiva Siddhānta, and the śrauta ones are possibly the āgamas accepted by Trika (Kashmir Śaivism).

Answer (score 1):

shrauta shaiva agama could be the one used in nataraja temple chidambaram as the [temple website](http://www.chidambaramnataraja.org/deekshithar.html) mentions about worship procedure laid out by patanjali to sages which is also referred in [chidambaram mahatmya](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/chidambara-mahatmyam-greatness-of-supreme-divine-lord-nataraja-nad918/), part of [skanda purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/skandapurana) :

> *The temple is managed and administered hereditarily by the Chidambaram Dikshitar – a **class of Vaideeka Brahmins whom, legends
> say, were brought here, from Mt. Kailas, by Saint Patanjali**,
> specifically for the performance of the daily rituals and maintenance
> of the Chidambaram temple.*
>
> ***These Deekshithars follow the Vedic rituals, unlike the Sivachariyars or Adhisaivars – who follow the agamic rituals for the
> worship of Lord Shiva. The rituals for the temple were collated from
> the Vedas and set by Patanjali**, who is said to have inducted the
> Deekshithars into the worship of Lord Shiva as Nataraja.*
>
> *In ancient times the Deekshithars, the community of hereditary priests were known as Muvariyavar, or the 3000 of Tillai. **The
> Chidambaram Mahatmyam recounts of their arrival in Tillai just as Lord
> Nataraja started his dance there.** Thus they were the chosen
> guardians of the Lord’s worship and of the temple from its very
> conception.*